# PHP check if value exists in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL and I want to check if the value of the users input `$_POST['username']` already exists in my database (in the field `username`). I have tried this code:

```
$usernameExists = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = " . $_POST['username'];

if ($usernameExists) {
    echo "Exists"
}
```

I put this code after the `if (!empty...)` statement;

but nothing happened. If you need my full code, it is available here, but I assume the rest of it won't be helpful:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { // user is already logged in
    header("Location: index.php");
}

require('database.php');

$message = '';
$emailMessage = '';
$usernameMessage = '';
$passwordMessage = '';
$confirmMessage = '';

if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['confirmPassword'])) { // user submitted form; enter user

    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailMessage = 'Invalid email.';

    } elseif (strlen($_POST['username']) < 4 || strlen($_POST['username']) > 250) {
        $usernameMessage = 'Username has to be between 4 and 250 characters.';

    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z0-9]*$/", $_POST['username'])) {
        $usernameMessage = 'Username can only contain numbers and letters.';

    } elseif (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6 || strlen($_POST['password']) > 250) {
        $passwordMessage = 'Password has to be between 6 and 250 characters.';

    } elseif ($_POST['confirmPassword'] !== $_POST['password']) {
        $confirmMessage = 'Passwords don\'t match THONK';

    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) VALUES (:email, :username, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);

        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $message = 'Successfully created new user: ' . $_POST['username'];
        } else {
            $message = 'There was an error lol';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `username = " . $_POST['username']` is invalid SQL and opening you to SQL injections. Unless your usernames are all integers. Your current query with my name would be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = chris85`. Parameterize that query as you have elsewhere.

Comment: You are using prepared statements in your `INSERT` statement. Do the same for your `SELECT` statement and you should be set.

Comment: Also do you ever send `$usernameExists` to the DB? If not that is the first problem.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson For the moment I'm not worrying about prepared statements. I just want to get it to show up, but with the statement I put in the OP it didn't work. Once I get get that to echo if that username already exists, I will worry about making it secure ;)

Comment: That line of code assigns a string to a variable. That's all it does. It doesn't  matter that the string looks like a SQL statement... it's just a string. (If you were to send that string to the database to be executed as a SQL statement, it appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. Supply potentially unsafe values as *bind values* to a *prepared statement.)

Comment: @chris85 I think that's my problem. But I'm not sure what bit of the code will do that.

Comment: If you parameterize the query, it will work. If you don't, you need to wrap the username in single quotes (strings _must_ be quoted or the query will fail). However, this will leave you _wide open to sql injections_ and why you don't care about that is beyond me. You should _always_ think about writing secure code from the start. That will minimize the risk of forgetting/missing to fix that later.

Comment: Did someone else write the large code block? That is using the correct approach.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman The OP seems to be using PDO, not the procedural version of mysqli. Even if the OP _did_ use that, your example is invalid. That function takes two arguments, the first being the database link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the database using a prepared statement. Like this:

```
 $usernameExists = 0;
 $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindValue(':username',$_POST['username']);
 $stmt->execute();

 if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // row(s) returned
    $usernameExists = 1;
 } else {
    // no row returned
    $usernameExists = 0;
 }
 $stmt->closeCursor();
```

Then you can do this:

```
if ($usernameExists) {
   echo "Exists"
}
```